# Sugar CRM saves index.php file after migrating to new server

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, sugarcrm

i transferred a website over to a new server. as far as i can tell, everything came with it. databases, SSL, everything. It was a cpanel package script:

```
/scripts/pkgacct fileserv
```

its Sugar CRM. it still works on the old server, but when i try to use it on the new server, it just downloads index.php
and leaves me at a blank screen. any ideas? i was thinking possibly a PHP or Apache module or something, but I've never set up sugar CRM myself, and in setup guides, i couldn't find any special modules or anything that I need.

this is a problem i've dealt with before, but all the typical fixes aren't working. there are other websites running, so PHP and apache are working just fine. I edited .htaccess and everything too. but any suggestions at all would be very helpful. assume i've done absolutely nothing so far, just in case I missed something obvious.

Comment: Anything here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Comment: I'm trying a couple things. also i have full PHP/MySQL websites running on the server already, so PHP is definitely installed and running properly.

Comment: Just because other websites work doesn't mean that they all will. You can disable/enable PHP on single websites on the same server. Most likely you're missing `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` for that particular website.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's probably apache, either A) the new server does not have PHP installed and apache does not have the module installed either or B) apache does not have the module installed to execute php scripts.

I think the comment under your question is heading in the right direction:

[PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: well i don't see the actual source code, it's just downloading the file as a whole. granted, it's a full php file. there's no html mixed in or anything. Also, the server is currently running a few other PHP/MySQL websites so its not that. but do you know which modules i might check for? what Sugar CRM uses?